# *** WARNING: skipped 31093 bytes of output *** Databricks

Tags: python, api, shell, databricks, azure-databricks

I am currently using a shell script to get the API response in Databricks, but as the response is quite big I am getting this error

*** WARNING: skipped 31093 bytes of output ***
I am struggling to find how can I get the rest data from the response.

API call I am using  https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/databricks/dev-tools/api/latest/clusters#--list

sample code :

```
 export DATABRICKS_TOKEN=mytoken
 result=$(curl -X GET --header "Authorization: Bearer $DATABRICKS_TOKEN"\
 https://{adburl}/api/2.0/clusters/list)
 echo "$result"
```

Comment: I figured out that data bricks only shows limited data in their output window, I saved the API response in the data lake, and API response (entire data) is accurate

Answer (score 1):

you can check all printed values in your driver’s logs[image]

[image]